# Call JsonResult property from model in view of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have one class :

```
public class ShoppingCartVM
{
   public JsonResult CartRelatedItems { get; set; }
}
```

And a model that return

```
return new JsonResult
{
   Data = listItem,
   JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, 
};
```

In controller, I assign the value the propery `ShoppingCartVM` of the `ShoppingCartVM` object.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     var _relatedItem = qm.GetRelatedItemCart((
                                  HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?
                                  qm.GetCustomer(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).PriceLevel.Value : 0
                               ));
     ShoppingCartVM scvm = new ShoppingCartVM()
     {
         CartRelatedItems = _relatedItem
     }
     return View(scvm);
  }
```

Could anyone tell me, how can I loop the property `CartRelatedItems` to display by ajax in the View of my asp.net mvc project.

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Partial or RenderPartial for ajax calls using Razor. For example

```
@Html.Partial("mypartialview")
```

or

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("mypartialview"); %>
```

Following link could help for detailed on Partial or RenderPartial.

http://www.compiledthoughts.com/2011/01/aspnet-mvc-razor-partial-views-with.html

Comment: How can I use that? Can you add more detail please?